# Run xargs on the first word on a line

Tags: xargs

Is there a way to run [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) on only the first argument of a line? So if my input is the default output from a `grep`, like this:

```
./file1       "matching string"
./file2       "matching 2"
```

What I want to do is open all of the file names in [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) with something like `| xargs vim`.

Can I tell `xargs` to just grab the first word of each line?

I know there are other ways of doing this, including piping to [AWK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) to strip all the extra line garbage, and getting grep to only return the filename - I'm curious whether you can do this with xargs.

Comment: That's why then invented `cut`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have stated, generic `xargs` can't do this alone.  Sticking with common Unix tools, you'll need to use the `cut` command to strip off the extra information before you send it to xargs.

Assuming your input looks like this:

```
./file1       "matching string"
./file2       "matching 2"
```

You can use `|cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs -n 1 vi` to run the commands.

- The `cut -f 1 -d ' '` command only sends on what is in column 1 to the output.
- The `xargs -n 1 vi` tells xargs to run vi, but only use one file at a time.

It is ok to remove the `-n 1` if you want to use a single vi instance to edit all the files (to keep copy/paste buffers across files).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with xargs itself.

So your options are to make `grep` output just what you need to pass to `xargs`, or pipe through `cut` to strip out what you need in between.

Remember this is the *nix way - to keep each utility as focussed as possible, and use them in combination to achieve results (rather than duplicating functionality in multiple utilities).

Comment: "make grep output just what you need to pass to xargs": That's the -l flag.  "grep -l" just outputs the names of the files that match.  You can pipe that to xargs.  If your filenames might have spaces in them, use "xargs -d \\n".

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel you can do:

```
... | grep ... | parallel --colsep ' +' -X --tty vi {1}
```

It works with emacs, too:

```
... | grep ... | parallel --colsep ' +' -X --tty emacs {1}
```

You can install GNU Parallel simply by:

```
wget http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/plain/src/parallel
chmod 755 parallel
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.